# Record audio from more than one AudioBufferSourceNode in Web Audio API

Tags: javascript, audio, web-audio-api

I am developing a simple drum pad in Javascript and using the Web Audi API for the audio.

The application should have the option to record the mix created and save it to file.

I have been looking at solutions like Matt Diamond's Recorder.js ([GitHub page](https://github.com/mattdiamond/Recorderjs))

and WebAudioRecorder.js ([GitHub page](https://github.com/higuma/web-audio-recorder-js))

My issue is that each cell in the drum pad is a separate AudioBufferSourceNode and both of those libraries receive one sourcenode as input in the constructor.

To record the whole mix would I would need the libraries to be able to record more than one sourcenode at a time, or to connect each AudioBufferSourceNode in the drum pad to a Web Audio API grouping node that I could than pass on to a recording library.

I have been looking at the Web Audio API documentation ([docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Audio_API)) and there does not seem to be node for this functionality.

Basically, my question is how do I write more than one AudioBufferSourceNode to the same file at the same time?

Regards,
Elvar

Answer (score -1):

GainNodes are perfect for this- just connect them all to a single gain node, leave the gain at 1, and connect it to your recording node.  You may want to look at MediaRecorder, btw.

Comment: Please add more detail. What do I do? This doesn't answer the question